# Undefined method `unloadable' when upgrade to rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a controller `SocketController` inherit `WebsocketRails::BaseController`

```
class SocketController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

After upgrade rails version to 7.0.4 
When I run `rails s` got this error
How to fix it, please!!

```
Failure/Error:
  class SocketController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `unloadable' for WebsocketRails::BaseController:Class

          unloadable controller
          ^^^^^^^^^^
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/websocket-rails-0.7.0/lib/websocket_rails/base_controller.rb:45:in `inherited'
# ./app/controllers/socket_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:30:in `require'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:169:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:164:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:296:in `block in eager_load_all'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `each'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:294:in `eager_load_all'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
# ./vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I think:
Could it be that 1 gem version or 1 configuration is not suitable, causing it to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is that for, your controller is reloadable because it is in `app/controllers`, like any other Ruby file in those directories.

That gem has not had activity for years. I'd suggest that you reopen `WebsocketRails::BaseController` in an initializer, define a dummy `unloadable` class method in it that does nothing, and see if your controllers reload as expected.